# Half year date format

Tags: javascript, momentjs, date-formatting

I want to get the half year date format for ex:
If i have date 2020-01-01 the date format must be H1 and for 2020-08-01 the date format must be H2
I have achieved the quarter date format for ex: 2020-01-01 -> Q1 and for 2020-04-01 -> Q2 in the following manner

```
const baseDateM = moment(`${year}-${month}-01`, 'YYYY-MMM-DD');
var periodAsDatesM = []; // using var
var dateFormat;
dateFormat = '[Q]Q';
periodAsDatesM = [
          baseDateM,
          baseDateM.clone().subtract(1, 'quarters'),
          baseDateM.clone().subtract(2, 'quarters'),
          baseDateM.clone().subtract(3, 'quarters'),
          baseDateM.clone().add(1, 'quarters'),
          baseDateM.clone().add(2, 'quarters'),
 ];
let yearsArray = _.uniq(periodAsDatesM.map(dtM => dtM.format('YYYY')));
const myPeriodArr = periodAsDatesM.map(dtM => dtM.format(dateFormat));
```

Here the myPeriodArr contains [Q1,Q2] based on the dates,
But now when when I follow this for half yearly
myPeriodArr contains [H0,H0] irrespective of date.
I tried the following for half yearly.

```
dateFormat = '[H]H';
        periodAsDatesM = [
          baseDateM,
          baseDateM.clone().subtract(6, 'months'),
          baseDateM.clone().subtract(12, 'months'),
          baseDateM.clone().subtract(18, 'months'),
          baseDateM.clone().add(6, 'months'),
          baseDateM.clone().add(12, 'months'),
        ];
let yearsArray = _.uniq(periodAsDatesM.map(dtM => dtM.format('YYYY')));
const myPeriodArr = periodAsDatesM.map(dtM => dtM.format(dateFormat));
```

I want to get the format of date in H1 and H2
Ex:
If `periodAsDatesM` contains : `[2018-12-01,2019-06-01,2019-12-01,2020-06-01]`
then `myPeriodArr`  should be : `[H2,H1,H2,H1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question's tags, it looks like you're using momentjs. [There's an issue about this in the momentjs GitHub project.](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/3582)

Adapted from [a comment there](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/3582#issuecomment-381762982):

```js
const halfFormatted = `H${moment(new Date()).get('quarter') < 3 ? 1 : 2}`

console.log(halfFormatted)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

```js
const halfFormat = `H${date.get('quarter') < 3) ? 1 : 2}`
```